# How to verify the toast message via appium with uiautomator2?

Tags: java, appium

I have write one app which include one button and it will show one toast message.

```
public void onClickShowToast(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Change port successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And then, i write one test case with appium try to verify it.

```
//APPIUM Version: 1.6.3;
//JAVA: 1.8;
//JAVA Client: 5.0.0;
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);

driver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@text,'Button')]").click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'port')]")))
```

But, the result is fail:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath:
>   //*contains(@text, 'port')

Answer (score 0):

The trick is finding the right **XPath**. I managed this using one of the following:

```
//android.widget.Toast
//android.widget.Toast[@text='toast text']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can capture the toast like this:

`WebElement toastView = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast[1]"));
 String text = toastView.getAttribute("name");`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088919/how-to-capture-the-toast-in-android-with-appium/46088920#46088920) is my solution.