# How to capture the Toast in Android with appium

Tags: android, appium, toast

I used like this,but not found.

`WebElement element = androidDriver.findElementByClassName(android.widget.Toast);`

So I search in every major forum and portal,they solved it by blow:

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(androidDriver, 3);
 WebElement toastView = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
          By.xpath(".//*[contains(@text,'" + toast + "')]")));`

But it works well in the condition of you has known the *toast text*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my finally solution:

`WebElement toastView = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast[1]"));
 String text = toastView.getAttribute("name");`

**Thanks for the xpath grammar!**

Comment: Not sure how this was down-voted. Works great for me and this was 1 year ahead of the game. I have posted some updated code. Good work!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated answer:

```
WebElement toastView = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast[1]"));
//USE THE RETRIEVED TEXT TO ASSERT ETC
System.out.println("TOAST = " + toastView.getText());
```